# bash: IF condition with keyworld within FOR loop

Tags: bash, for

I am dealing with simple for loop, which loop the filles and execute on it some commands. I need to set up the filter with IF statement to consider only file started with the keyword "AllBoxes":

```
  for pdb in "${storage}"/"${experiment}"/*.pdb ; do
    pdb_name=$(basename "$pdb" .pdb)
    # if file starts with pharase AllBoxes do something on the file
    if [[ ${pdb_name} =='AllBoxes*' ]] ; then
    echo Vizualisation of ${pdb_name} is being processed!
    fi
    done
```

This gives me an error in the IF statement.

Also would it be enought to skipp all of the rest filles (that does not start with "AllBoxes" keyworld? Need I introduce something like Else or Elif Break to exit the loop ?

Comment: So, what error is it that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably because you need a space after the `==` however you won't be able to use wildcards like that in an expanded test.  You could use `=~` to do regex matching (something like `AllBoxes.*`) however if you quote it, it will be treated literally.  If you only care about `AllBoxes` files however you could just modify your loop to:

```
for pdb in "${storage}/${experiment}"/AllBoxes*.pdb ; do
```

Comment: thank you! you are right, but I am testing IF as the conditional filter :-)  and how to match in the same manner the directory names containat "AllBoxes" in any part of the name ? I tried via if [[ ${dir_name} =~ *AllBoxes* ]] , but it did not work

Comment: Are you checking the dir name or the filename?

Comment: now I am checking DIR name but it was defined in the simmilar manner as filename: for d in "${output}"/*/; do; dir_name=${d%*/}; dir_name=$(basename "$dir_name") so I apply IF on $dir_name

Comment: If you have a different question please post it as a new question.

Comment: right thank you! I just wondering acrually how to use the same condition if [[ ${name} =~ 'AllBoxes*' ]]  but when 'AllBoxes' is located in ANY part of the string defined as (basename)

Comment: @user3470313 Since the `*` is in single-quotes, it's treated as a literal asterisk character rather than a wildcard. You want `if [[ ${name} =~ 'AllBoxes'* ]]` (the single-quotes are optional) to match "AllBoxes" at the beginning of `$name`, or `if [[ ${name} =~ *'AllBoxes'* ]]` to match it anywhere in `$name`.